# Remove grey box around GIFs in Python Kivy?

Tags: ios, image, kivy, gif

I a creating an app in Python using Kivy, but when I use this GIF which has a transparent background, a grey box appears around the GIF. I don't understand why this is?

Here's the grey box (the dots are the gif):

[image: The grey box around GIF error]

The GIF in question: https://ibb.co/dMnxWVW

And here's the Python code for the GIF:

```
    def on_press(self):
       self.ids.mic_image.anim_loop = 0
       self.ids.mic_image.source = "Mic_Pressed.gif"
```

And here's the .kv code for the GIF:

```
Image:
    source: "Mic_Pressed.gif"
    opacity: 0
    anim_delay: 0
    size_hint: (0.6,0.6)
    pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y": 0.2}


Image:
    id: mic_image
    source: "Mic_Static.gif"
    opacity: 1
    anim_delay: 0
    size_hint: (0.6,0.6)
    pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y": 0.2}


Button:
    id: mic
    background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
    pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "y":0.09}
    size_hint: (0.2,0.19)
    on_press:
        root.on_press()
```

The app initially displays "Mic_Static.gif" (without any grey box). When the button (which is the same size as the GIF) is pressed, "Mic_Pressed.gif" is displayed, however it has the surrounding grey box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is an issue with your gif file. Try this replacement [image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work - any other ideas?

Comment: I've figured out a solution: I used a gif maker online to prevent stacking of gif frames and it works perfectly now.